# Adding image to stripe checkout session for mutiple products

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js, stripe-payments

I am using stripe payment gateway for my Nextjs application. I have mutiple products to add for the checkout but I get error when adding image to the product_data for the line_items.

The API works for only name in the product_data object. The error response i get when i add image is statusCode 400, invalid array

```
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      let requestArray = req.body;
      var result = requestArray.map((ele: any) => ({
        price_data: {
          currency: "usd",
          unit_amount: Number(ele.price) * 100,
          product_data: {
            name: ele.name,
            images:ele.imageURL
          },
        },
        quantity: ele.qty,
      }));

      // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        line_items: result,
        mode: "payment",
        success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/checkout?success=true`,
        cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/checkout?canceled=true`,
      });

      res.json({ id: session.id });
    } catch (err: any) {
      res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
    res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
  }
}
```

I will appreciate any suggestion

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact error message you get? Also can you share the content of the `result` array?

Comment: `images` must be an array of strings. I guess `ele.imageURL` is of type `string`. You can add up to 8 URLs of images according to the [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/object).

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine, Thank you soo much , i missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`images` must be an `array` of `string`. You can add up to 8 URLs of images according to the [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/object).

`ele.imageURL` is of type `string`.